# Write a Reusable Update Query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I am trying to write a reusable UPDATE Query in PHP based on Jeffery's INSERT query on laracast

This is Jeff's Insert Query

```
public function insert($table, $parameters)
{
$sql = sprintf(
        'INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)',
        $table,
        implode(', ', array_keys($parameters)),
        ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($parameters))

    );
    try {
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($parameters);
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        die("Something Went Wrong");
    }
}
```

This is the Update Code I am Trying to Write

```
public function update($table, $parameters, $Condition)
{
    $sql = sprintf(
        'UPDATE %s SET %s=%s WHERE ' . $Condition,
        $table,
        implode('=,', array_keys($parameters))
        ,
        ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($parameters))

    );


    try {
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($parameters);
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        die("Something Went Wrong");
    }

}
```

I want to make it as reusable as the Insert Query by just passing the Data in

All Help is Highly Appricated

Comment: Not sure I understand. You can save the statement as a member of the class instance and reuse it again ONLY if you have the same parameters and values, then you just need to execute the statement again, but with the different parameters

Comment: Beware, [your code is vulnerable to sql injection](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example)

Comment: @AlonEitan it is not a statement but a function he wants to reuse

Comment: @YourCommonSense So I don't understand the "reuse" part - Ignoring the risk in this code that you mentioned, they can pass multidimensional array to the function where each dimension represent the values of a new row to insert - They create the statement once and iterate over the values array and executing it multiple times for each row. Is that not correct?

Comment: @AlonEitan forget PDO and statements. That's just a function. Functions tend to be reused, with different sets of parameters.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Oh! Like an ORM style function? So is this a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526190/difference-between-orm-and-pdo) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346457/some-orm-using-pdo)?

Comment: So you want to write your own query builder and are asking on SO how to do that? This is IMHO "too broad". Just use an existing solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **really bad idea**. Don't do it.

Instead I would recommend creating custom [data mappers](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) for your entities, that would contain hand-crafted SQL, with properly bound parameters/values.

But as an experiment, this is what I came up with:

```php
public function update($table, $parameters, $conditions)
{
    $sql = sprintf(
        'UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE %s',
        $table,
        implode(', ',array_map(
            function ($key) {
                return "{$key} = :s_{$key}";
            },
            array_keys($parameters)
        )),
        implode(' AND ',array_map(
            function ($key) {
                return "{$key} = :w_{$key}";
            },
            array_keys($conditions)
        ))
    );

    $parameters = array_combine(
        array_map(function($key){ return ":s_{$key}"; }, array_keys($parameters)),
        $parameters
    ) + array_combine(
        array_map(function($key){ return ":w_{$key}"; }, array_keys($conditions)),
        $conditions
    );

    try {
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($parameters);
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        die("Something Went Wrong");
    }

}
```

Keep in mind that, is your "users" can somehow affect the **keys** of either `$parameters` or `$conditions` arrays, then this code becomes vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

> **P.S.**
>   In your original example, you had `$Condition` parameter simply concatenated to the end of your query. That would create a huge risk of SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient[1] way to generate UPDATE statements from an array of field names with named parameters that can 
be executed with arbitrary data (e.g. using PDOStatements).

[1] efficient: It uses `sprintf` exclusivly to do the interpolation, no concatenation.

Indications:

- you need to persist some objects, and Doctrine or the likes would be
  overkill
- your objects don't have any funky transformations required
  on their data before saving
- users will have no opportunity to modify the list of field names (in my case it was hardcoded into the PHP)

We're all adults and can decide for ourselves when the above indications apply.

If you have an associative array, then just take the array_keys of it first.

```
$tablename = 'character';
$fields = [
    'name',
    'class',
    'hitpoints',
    'battlecry'
];

$first = array_pop($fields);
$fmt = array_reduce($fields, function($carry, $item) {
    return sprintf($carry, sprintf(', %1$s = :%1$s %%s', $item));
}, sprintf(' SET %1$s = :%1$s %%s', $first));

$sql = sprintf('UPDATE %s %s ', $tablename, sprintf($fmt, ';'));

echo $fmt; // UPDATE character SET battlecry = :battlecry , name = :name , class = :class , hitpoints = :hitpoints ;
```